# Pandas count number of rows that match on certain fields but don't match on other fields

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a Python pandas dataframe `df` that has several columns including `df['FRST_NM']`, df[`'LAST_NM'`], df[`'BRTH_DT'`], and df[`'ADDRESS'`].

I want to find the number of rows in the database where `FRST_NM` and `LAST_NM` match, but `BRTH_DT` and `ADDRESS` don't match. I'm ultimately trying to calculate the likelihood that a first name and last name match but their respective birth date and address don't match. It's a data integrity project.

For example, I want to count all the instances of `FRST_NM` `John` and `LAST_NM` `Doe` where their respective `BRTH_DT` and `ADDRESS` fields don't match. Just to be clear, I dont want to have to input values for `FRST_NM` and `LAST_NM`.

I think I'm looking for a GroupBy clause that says GroupBy `FRST_NM`, `LAST_NM` and **not** `BRTH_DT` and `ADDRESS`, but I'm not sure that something like this exists.

Comment: Does this dataframe originate in a relational database? I see effortless SQL here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the number of rows with unique `BRTH_DT` and `ADDRESS` using

```
df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['FRST_NM','LAST_NM'])['ADDRESS'].count()
```

(Applying `drop_duplicates` to the entire DataFrame is significantly faster than my
[first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b70ae251-d84e-457f-a3c6-0f875c805296/view-source), which used a custom function to call `drop_duplicates` on each group.) For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2016)
N = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({'FRST_NM':np.random.choice(['Charles','Edgar Allan','Agatha'], N),
                   'LAST_NM':np.random.choice(['Dickens', 'Poe', 'Christie'], N),
                   'BRTH_DT':np.random.choice([1812, 1809, 1890], N),
                   'ADDRESS':np.random.choice(['Landport','Boston','Torquay'], N)})

result = pd.DataFrame(
    {'num_unique' : (df.drop_duplicates()
                       .groupby(['FRST_NM','LAST_NM'])['ADDRESS']
                       .count()), 
     'count' : df.groupby(['FRST_NM', 'LAST_NM'])['ADDRESS'].count()})
result['percent'] = result['num_unique'] / result['count']
print(result)
```

yields

```
                      count  num_unique   percent
FRST_NM     LAST_NM                              
Agatha      Christie      4           4  1.000000
            Dickens       8           4  0.500000
            Poe           7           5  0.714286
Charles     Christie      7           6  0.857143
            Dickens       4           4  1.000000
            Poe           9           6  0.666667
Edgar Allan Christie      4           3  0.750000
            Dickens       4           3  0.750000
            Poe           3           3  1.000000
```

Note that it is a complete (and wonderful) fluke that Agatha Christie, Charles Dickens, and Edgar Allan Poe come out with 100% unique rows. If you try other random seeds you'll see this doesn't often happen...